# Groovy: Xml returned by StreamingMarkupBuilder

Tags: xml, groovy

How can I access xml elements returned by `StreamingMarkupBuilder`.

```
def element = {
   Element {
      Element1("value1")
      Element2("value2")
      Element3("value3") 
   }
}
def xml = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind(element)
```

Now I want value of `Element2`. I have tried

```
println xml.Element.Element2.text()
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don;t believe you can, you'd need to parse the output from StreamingMarkupBuilder:

```
println new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml.toString() ).Element2.text()
```